# xcode Objective C add object item from nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an Object class like this

```
@interface Recipe : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; // name of recipe
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *prepTime; // preparation time
@end
```

Normaly, I add new object by this way.

```
Recipe *myClass = [Recipe new];
myClass.name = @"This is name";
myClass.prepTime = @"This is time";

Recipe *myClass1 = [Recipe new];
myClass1.name = @"This is name1";
myClass1.prepTime = @"This is time1";

Recipe *myClass2 = [Recipe new];
myClass2.name = @"This is name2";
myClass2.prepTime = @"This is time2";
```

Now, I have a dictionary from array and I want to add all value in dictionary into object in a for loop each.

```
NSMutableArray *recipes;
NSArray *somoData = [self downloadSoMo];
for (NSDictionary *dict in someData)
{
    Recipe *myClass = [Recipe new];
    myClass.name = [dict objectForKey:@"DreamName"];
    myClass.prepTime = [dict objectForKey:@"Number"];
    [recipes addObject:myClass];
}
```

Code above is not working, I don't know why, please help me to fix it

Comment: Why are you storing preparation time as a String?   Wouldn't it be better as an Int representing the number of minutes or seconds?

Comment: @Paulw11 this is just a sample code, `prepTime` I will use as a description as well.

Comment: What does "Code above is not working" mean? What's not working? What symptom are you seeing? (My guess is that nothing is getting added to your recipes array, since you never created an array. You need to change the declaration of the recipes array to allocate an `NSMutableArray` object: `NSMutableArray *recipes = [NSMutableArray new]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate **recipes** 
e.g.
  NSMutableArray *recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
NSMutableArray *recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *somoData = [self downloadSoMo];
for (NSDictionary *dict in someData)
{
    Recipe *myClass = [Recipe new];
    myClass.name = [dict objectForKey:@"DreamName"];
    myClass.prepTime = [dict objectForKey:@"Number"];
    [recipes addObject:myClass];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make a method in `Recipe` class to create an instance of it.

Like this,

In `Recipe.h`

```
- (instancetype) initRecipeWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dicRecipe;
```

In `Recipe.m`

```
- (instancetype) initRecipeWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dicRecipe {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
       self.name = [dicRecipe objectForKey:@"DreamName"];
       self.prepTime = [dicRecipe objectForKey:@"Number"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *somoData = [self downloadSoMo];
for (NSDictionary *dict in someData)
{
    Recipe *myClass = [[Recipe alloc] initRecipeWithDictionary:dict];
    [recipes addObject:myClass];
}
```

By doing this way, your initialization logic will be written at a single place, and if in case you want to change something, it will be easy to handle it by changing in a single file `Recipe`.